# IllegalAccessException when trying to read protected property from class with different ClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, protected

I have a following files:

```
src/
 |- cltest/
 |   |- Main.class
 |   |- Test.class
 |   `- TestingClassLoader.class
 `- data (a class cltest.LoadedClass without an extension)
```

Main.java:

```
package cltest;

public class Main {
  protected static String field = "TestTestTest";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("cltest.Test");
    Class.forName("cltest.LoadedClass", true, new TestingClassLoader());
  }
}
```

Test.java and /data

```
package cltest;

public class Test /* or LoadedClass for /data file */ {
  static {
    System.out.println(Main.field);
  }
}
```

TestingClassLoader.java

```
package cltest;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class TestingClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
  public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data");
      byte[] buf = new byte[256]; int r;
      while ((r = is.read(buf)) != -1) baos.write(buf, 0, r);
      byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

      return defineClass(null, data, 0, data.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ClassNotFoundException(name, e);
    }
  }
}
```

This code gives me an error on line `Class.forName("cltest.LoadedClass", true, new TestingClassLoader());`:

```
TestTestTest //  (output of 1st Class.forName() call)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field cltest.Main.field from class cltest.LoadedClass
  at cltest.LoadedClass.<clinit>(LoadedClass.java:5)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
  at cltest.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: I think the reason is Main.java is loaded by bootstrap loader, cltest.LoadedClass is loaded by custom class loader and not satisfying VMSpec 5.4.4 "R is protected and is declared in a class C, and D is either a subclass of C or C itself."  Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ConstantPool.doc.html

Comment: But `Test` is not subclass of `Main`, but has access to field `field`

Comment: For Test you are not using custom loader, so might be that Main and Test are in same runtime package, which satisfies "R is either protected or package private (that is, neither public nor protected nor private), and is declared by a class in the same runtime package as D".

Comment: Is there any way to put them in a same runtime package? I want load plugin that must have access to protected methods of main code

Comment: I think one way to make them in same runtime package would be make sure they are loaded by same classloader "The runtime package of a class or interface is determined by the package name and defining class loader of the class or interface".

Comment: There are some mechanisms defined in this link, I have never implemented them, so can't guarantee how it works. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ConstantPool.doc.html#72007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way for this to work is for LoadedClass and Main to be in the same classloader (classes are only truly in the same package if they have the same package name *and* classloader).

you talk about a "plugin" which needs to access protected methods of main.  this is a poor design for a plugin system.  if you control these classes, then make the necessary methods public instead of protected.

Comment: Thank you. I will use reflection to invoke `defineClass` on `Main.class.getClassLoader()`